# Explode function does not work with struct in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I cannot resolve `explode('learner')` due to data type mismatch: input to function explode should be array or map type, not struct<_1:structname:string,email:string,city:string,_2:structname:string,email:string,city:string,_3:structname:string,email:string,city:string>;;

```py
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import Row
    
course_structure = Row('course_id','course_name','fee')
course1=course_structure('1001','hadoop','7000')
course2=course_structure('1002','spark','8000')
course3=course_structure('1003','terraform','9000')
course4=course_structure('1004','python','3000')

learner = Row('name','email','city')
learner1=learner('amit','amit@hadoop.exe','mumbai')
learner2=learner('rakesh','rakesh@hadoop.exe','pune')
learner3=learner('money','money@hadoop.exe','newyork')
learner4=learner('simon', 'simon@hadoop.exe','hongkong')
learner5=learner('venkat','venkat@hadoop.exe','chennai')
learner6=learner('rama','ram@hadoop.exe','aus')
learner7=learner('dal','daljeet@hadoop.exe','london')

courselearner1 = Row(course=course1,learner=(learner1,learner2,learner3))
courselearner2 = Row(course=course2,learner=(learner3,learner4,learner2))
courselearner3 = Row(course=course3,learner=(learner5,learner6,learner4))
courselearner4 = Row(course=course4,learner=(learner7,learner1,learner5))

seq1=courselearner1,courselearner2                
seq2=courselearner3,courselearner4
    
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(seq1)
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(seq2)

combinedf = df1.union(df2)

combinedf.printSchema()
combinedf.show(truncate=False)

combinedf.select("course.*",explode("learner"))
```

Answer (score 1):

explode only works with `array or map` types but you are having all **`struct`** type.

You can directly access struct by **`struct_field_name.*`**

**`Example:`**

```
combinedf.printSchema()
#root
# |-- course: struct (nullable = true)
# |    |-- course_id: string (nullable = true)
# |    |-- course_name: string (nullable = true)
# |    |-- fee: string (nullable = true)
# |-- learner: struct (nullable = true)
# |    |-- _1: struct (nullable = true)
# |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
# |    |    |-- email: string (nullable = true)
# |    |    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
# |    |-- _2: struct (nullable = true)
# |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
# |    |    |-- email: string (nullable = true)
# |    |    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
# |    |-- _3: struct (nullable = true)
# |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
# |    |    |-- email: string (nullable = true)
# |    |    |-- city: string (nullable = true)

combinedf.select("course.*","learner.*").select("course_id","course_name","fee","_1.*","_2.*","_3.*").show()
#+---------+-----------+----+------+------------------+-------+------+-----------------+--------+------+-----------------+--------+
#|course_id|course_name| fee|  name|             email|   city|  name|            email|    city|  name|            email|    city|
#+---------+-----------+----+------+------------------+-------+------+-----------------+--------+------+-----------------+--------+
#|     1001|     hadoop|7000|  amit|   amit@hadoop.exe| mumbai|rakesh|rakesh@hadoop.exe|    pune| money| money@hadoop.exe| newyork|
#|     1002|      spark|8000| money|  money@hadoop.exe|newyork| simon| simon@hadoop.exe|hongkong|rakesh|rakesh@hadoop.exe|    pune|
#|     1003|  terraform|9000|venkat| venkat@hadoop.exe|chennai|  rama|   ram@hadoop.exe|     aus| simon| simon@hadoop.exe|hongkong|
#|     1004|     python|3000|   dal|daljeet@hadoop.exe| london|  amit|  amit@hadoop.exe|  mumbai|venkat|venkat@hadoop.exe| chennai|
#+---------+-----------+----+------+------------------+-------+------+-----------------+--------+------+-----------------+--------+
```

Comment: Thank you! Actually after explode i need to grouping based on email who has subscribed how many courses
***
email                                count 
simon@hadoop.exe         2
amit@hadoop.exe   2
money@hadoop.exe        2
daljeet@hadoop.exe  1                      ***

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer that i have found

---

---

```
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import Row
course_structure = Row('course_id','course_name','fee')
course1=course_structure('1001','hadoop','7000')
course2=course_structure('1002','spark','8000')
course3=course_structure('1003','terraform','9000')
course4=course_structure('1004','python','3000')
learner = Row('name','email','city')
learner1=learner('amit','amit@hadoop.exe','mumbai')
learner2=learner('rakesh','rakesh@hadoop.exe','pune')
learner3=learner('money','money@hadoop.exe','newyork')
learner4=learner('simon', 'simon@hadoop.exe','hongkong')
learner5=learner('venkat','venkat@hadoop.exe','chennai')
learner6=learner('ram','ram@hadoop.exe','aus')
learner7=learner('daljeet','daljeet@hadoop.exe','london')
courselearner1 = Row(course=list(course1),learner=list((list(learner1),list(learner2),list(learner3))))
courselearner2 = Row(course=list(course2),learner=list((list(learner3),list(learner4),list(learner2))))
courselearner3 = Row(course=list(course3),learner=list((list(learner5),list(learner6),list(learner4))))
courselearner4 = Row(course=list(course4),learner=list((list(learner7),list(learner1),list(learner5))))
seq1=courselearner1,courselearner2                
seq2=courselearner3,courselearner4
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(seq1)
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(seq2)
combinedf = df1.union(df2)
df = combinedf.withColumn("learner",explode("learner"))
df.show(truncate=False)
course_id =   df["course"].getItem(0)
course_name = df["course"].getItem(1)
course_fees = df["course"].getItem(2)
learner_name = df["learner"].getItem(0)
learner_email =df["learner"].getItem(1)
learner_city = df["learner"].getItem(2)
learnerdf = df.select(course_id,course_name,course_fees,learner_name,learner_email,learner_city) \
        .select(col("course[1]").alias("course_name"), \
           col("learner[0]").alias("learner_name"), \
           col("learner[1]").alias("email"), \
           col("learner[2]").alias("city")).groupBy("email").count().show()
```

---

---